# Homerun for KDE, how to enable?

Tags: 14.04, kde

I have installed KDE and homerun extension for it, but I can not find any clue how to launch/enable/configure it.
I have ubuntu 14.04, KDE 4.13.3 and I have done this method:
https://launchpad.net/~blue-shell/+archive/ubuntu/homerun

Where can I find this option?

thx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homerun can be used as a plasmoid (both on the panel and on the desktop), but is maily used as a desktop layout.
So:

- Right click desktop
- Desktop settings
- Layout: Homerun
- Set the background and behaviour to whatever pleases you.

Job done!

Comment: Thx :) It was not clear how to do that. OTherwise I could also add a widget to the KDE panels which opens a nice homerun desktop.